# Date format not consistent for a particular column in .csv file using app engine in peoplesoft

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, peoplesoft

I am generating a report in .csv format. The file is having date fields. In those date fields, the date is coming in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and "dd-mm-yyyy format".
I have used to_char(date,'DD-MM-YYYY') for all date fields. Still I am not getting consistent date format. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you opening the CSV in excel or in notepad?

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve a date type from the DB and use a string field in the output file. In peoplecode use: DateToLocalizedString

[PeopleSoft Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcl/book.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm)